# How to create a mockup that looks like a physical document or product

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, gimp

I would like to showcase samples of Microsoft Word documents. The example below shows what a document might would look like if it was printed.

[image: Example image from fiverr ad]

This would be the work done (in this case cv's) with word documents and use inkscape to have the same artwork on a hypothetical final product.

Source: [Fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com/tonnygingers/diligently-edit-rewrite-and-polish-your-resume-cv?context=advanced_search&context_type=rating&context_referrer=search_gigs&pckg_id=1&pos=10&funnel=13e3acf2-25a7-4300-8e2f-59e6ce00625a)

What tools or general workflow should I use to create a mockup like this from a Word document?

Comment: there's no specific name for this technique, it's just an image with  perspective and shadows applied to it

Comment: also, please [edit your question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/83176/edit) to include the image, this way we don't need to click on a link just to understand what are you talking about. Link rot is an issue on the site.

Comment: @SteveGearth I've edited the question to ask about *how* to do this, rather than *what to call it*, which seems to be what you were intending to ask. Please edit your question though to explain what you've already tried and what specific problems you are having. There are many ways to do something like this.

Comment: Hi thanks for all the help with this question I really appreacite,@Luciano  as in regard to the image i am not allowed still I appreaciate the editing and pointing that out.
@Scribblemacher appreacite molding the question better , as the name it seemed what I needed in order to get to that stage of the picture.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call that a technique. the only name that I would use to call that kind of previews is ***mockup design***, in which you apply your artwork on a hypothetical final product.

I would say there is no way to apply a word document to an mockup image unless you exported your word file in an image format such as PNG, JPEG or similar and used a software like Adobe Photoshop to apply your exported word document to the mockup image.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, I really appreaciate the support with that, the mockup desing, I was trying to do is with inkspace, the same as in the image.